# can you use do-while instead of while(true) in this textbook exercise?

Tags: javascript

**Textbook exercise:**

Write the function sumInput() that:

1. Asks the user for values using prompt and stores the values in the array.
2. Finishes asking when the user enters a non-numeric value, an empty string, or presses “Cancel”.
3. Calculates and returns the sum of array items.

P.S. A zero 0 is a valid number, please don’t stop the input on zero.

**Textbook solution:**

```
function sumInput() {

  let numbers = [];

  while (true) {

    let value = prompt("A number please?", 0);

    // should we cancel?
    if (value === "" || value === null || !isFinite(value)) break;

    numbers.push(+value);
  }

  let sum = 0;
  for (let number of numbers) {
    sum += number;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Personally I dislike `while (true)` because it doesn't seem as intuitive. Would it be wrong to try to rewrite as a `do--while`? (Even if there's a special gotcha that makes `do--while` NOT work in this case, I'd STILL like to know if `while (true)` is just some... very accepted universal usage or not)

Something like:

```
function sumInput() {

  let numbers = [];

  do {
    let value = prompt("A number please?", 0);
    numbers.push(+value);
  }
  while ( (value !== "" || value !== null) && isFinite(value) );

  let sum = 0;
  for (let number of numbers) {
    sum += number;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with either approach, and you are going to see different programmers do it both ways. For example, I would probably do it the first way because it makes sense to me and seems pretty efficient. You would choose to do it the second way.

Comment: Your code behaves differently: it pushes the final empty/invalid value to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you can’t really use a do-while loop cleanly because the “push” statement might have to be executed zero times (if for example the user quits before entering any numbers). However, without the break you’re trying to avoid, every statement in the loop body is going to execute at least once. In your solution, you end up pushing the final invalid value onto the array every time, which could corrupt your result.

In general, I find do-while loops rarely useful, because (as with this example) you often need to break in the middle to avoid some final repeated bit (e.g. processing input).